# Apply corrections to Landsat images?

Tags: atmospheric-correction

Which software is better to do atmospheric and radiometric corrections in Landsat images?

After the corrections, I hope them to be used in supervised classification according to land use. So is it ok to correct the image by the MTL file of the image in ENVI? Or do I need to correct the 3 RGB bands seperately for this task?

Answer (score 1):

The intended maximum likelihood classification is purely a statistical technique, for the reason correction of atmospheric effects may not be necessary. Alternatively, You may opt for other image enhancement techniques to facilitate better selection of training samples directly from your image. You may also consider Landsat surface reflectance data which is offered by USGS/NASA. You may download the same from their website, i.e. earthexplorer.

Secondly, I would suggest you to utilize available bands of the Landsat except thermal band(s) to improve image classification results.

I am providing you following article "A survival guide to Landsat preprocessing" to enable you better understand pre-processing steps involved to calibrate Landsat data.

https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/ecy.1730

If you are using ENVI, there are multiple tools e.g. FLAASH, QUAC, 'Dark Object Subtraction' to derive Top of Atmosphere as well as Land Surface Reflectance from input image. However, you will have to match produced pixel reflectance values with library or field spectra to make tweaks in the tool parameters and validate/match the results.

Answer (score 0):

I used methodology from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PknESopCwjA) for ArcMap. Watch out for sine expression in Raster Calclulator, because it calculates values in radians, so before calculating sine of SUN ELEVATION,  it's simplier to calculate sine values in Excel or to [transform](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/sin.htm) it into degrees.